# Perforce Create new folder in a Stream Depot

Tags: perforce, perforce-stream

I have a Stream Depot - depot

I have a stream in that depot that I created called ProductGizmo

So in P4V I see that Gizmo lives under depot - i.e depot/ProductGizmo

I now want to make ProductGizmo live under a folder called ClientAcme - so that I want to see 
depot/ClientAcme/ProductGizmo.  This is strictly for organization of the depot.   ClientAcme is not a stream.

But when I go the File > New > Folder - Folder is grayed out.

Do folders have no meaning in a Stream Depot?

How can I move / organize streams in a stream Depot

Comment: I don't think Perforce depots really have the concept of a folder without at least one file as a child. Does your branch/stream actually have any files associated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So based on what I have read and heard - this can not be done - ugh!

Here is a link to some more discussion on perforce forums

http://forums.perforce.com/index.php?/topic/1191-streams-naming-structure-different-levels/

Answer (score 3):

Streams are rooted at a 2-level depth in the depot hierarchy. A stream will have a root like "//depotname/streamname".

Once you create a stream root, you can't change it. The shallow root depth is meant to discourage you from using the stream's root path as any kind of intelligent label. (The problem being that if you could use depot paths for classifying streams, you would invariably end up having to branch files when a stream's classification changes, which leaves you with convoluted branching history.)

If you need to implement a stream naming scheme, you can use the stream Name field., e.g.:

```
Stream:  //depot/ProductGizmo
Name:    ClientAcme-ProductGizmo
```

Stream names *can* be changed. The name is displayed in P4V, and you can search by name. E.g.:

```
p4 streams -F "Name=*Acme-*"
```

However, you can't use the name in commands as a substitute for the depot path.

You could also overload the 2nd path in the stream root with your naming scheme. E.g.:

```
//depot/ClientAcme-ProductGizmo
```

That is pretty much like using a deeper depot path, because it can't be changed, and you can use it in commands, e.g.:

```
p4 changes -m1 //depot/ClientAcme-...
```

Comment: Can a stream depot contain non stream folders?

Comment: No, stream depots are for stream folders only.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to ressurect this but because this is the first answer when you look for it in Google when you search for this topic, since a few years, in stream depots the admin can set a **stream depth**. Setting this **to 2 or more** results in folders inside the depot and would do what OP was looking for.  Unfortunately, you can only set this at depot creation time, so you cannot change it afterwards.
So the accepted answer no longer applies, at least **for Stream Depots**